# How can I place points at equal angles on a range starting from 0 and not repeating if the range is 360?

Tags: circles, angle

I want to place points at equal angles of a range. The first point should always be at 0 and the last point should always be equal to the range amount (unless 360 since I don't want points to overlap).
For example:

if my range is 90 degrees and I want to place 3 points:

- 1st @ 0 degrees
- 2nd @ 45 degrees
- 3rd @ 90 degrees

if my range is 180 degrees and I want to place 5 points:

- 1st @ 0
- 2nd @ 45
- 3rd @ 90
- 4th @ 135
- 5th @ 180

if my range is 0 / 360 degrees and I want to place 3 points:

- 1st @ 0 degrees
- 2nd @ 120 degrees
- 3rd @ 240 degrees

Is there a math formula for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first point is at zero.  The remaining $n-1$ points divide the range into equal parts.

Comment: This works fine unless the range is 360. When it's 360, 0 and 360 will cause the last point to overlap with the first point.

Comment: You exclude the point at 360 because it is already covered